# Ruby on Rails Syntax Error - seems unsolvable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, rails-activerecord

Newbie here, and trying to use CarrierWave to upload an image.  However when I get to localhost this error message keeps popping up

C:/Sites/redemo/app/models/listing.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_end

```
# GET /listings.json
 def index
  @listing =Listing.all
 end
```

Rails.root: C:/Sites/redemo

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/listings_controller.rb:7:in `index'

However, when I check listing.rb this is what I see

```
class Listings < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :image ImageUpLoader
end
```

Am I missing something obvious here?  I've tried looking through similar posts to no avail.  Please help, thank  you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a comma in your `mount_uploader` method arguments:

```
mount_uploader :image, ImageUpLoader
```

Basically, `mount_uploader` is a method like any other and it's receiving 2 arguments so they need to be delimited by a comma.